# How to drop table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

The problem is that I have this error:

> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'songs' already exists

This is my migration file:

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint; 
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration; 
class CreateSongsTable extends Migration 
{
    public function up() 
    {
        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

I think the solution will be just to delete the table then run migration again, so how can I drop a table in Laravel 5 using the command line? I am using MySQL.

Comment: if you have created the table from migration file then just rollback the migration, run this command in cli php artisan migrate:rollback

Comment: I did it and the error is still there

Comment: show your migration file where you created songs table

Comment: add the code in post not in the comment, nobody gonna read this if you post it like it, & there is no down function in your file that's why rollback didn't worked

Comment: edit the post and add the code there and i'll give correct code

Answer (score 109):

To drop a table, you may use the Schema::drop method:

```php
Schema::drop('users');

// Better
Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Comment: Thanks for your correct and concise answer, however, I would prefer to see examples that drop a less important table than 'users'. Perhaps Schema::drop('widgets'); and Schema::dropIfExists('widgets'); would lessen the risk of some newbie destroying their install?

Comment: I have a table with data and I forgot to add dropIfExists to my pivot table, is there any way to add this dropIfExists field in the down method without lost data?? @the-alpha

Comment: `Schema::dropIfExists('users');` deletes the `table` so without making a backup of your table you can't drop it if you need the data. @FaridVatani

Answer (score 45):

To drop a table in laravel, Create a first migration

**Step to drop a table**

```
$ php artisan make:migration drop_user_table
```

Add this to your migrate file inside up function  `Schema::drop('tableName');`

```
public function up() 
{
    Schema::dropIfExists(table('songs'));
    $table->increments('id');
    ...

}
```

then run

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

Comment: what would yo suggest for rollback the table to create it back again?

Comment: Schema::create?

Answer (score 24):

You can use drop or dropIfExists methods:

```
Schema::drop('users');

Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

You can also rollback if you want to drop your last migrated table

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

The migrate:reset command will roll back all of your application's migrations:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

The migrate:fresh command will drop all tables from the database and then execute the  migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh

php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: The rollback command should be `php artisan migrate:rollback`.

Answer (score 12):

You need a down method on your migration so that when you run `php artisan migrate:rollback` it can drop your database.

e.g.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint; 
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration; 

class CreateSongsTable extends Migration 
{ 
    public function up() 
    { 
        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) { 
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->integer('user_id'); 
            $table->string('title'); 
            $table->string('slug')->unique(); 
            $table->timestamps(); 
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        }); 
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('songs');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer to the question being asked! php artisan migrate runs the up() function, while php artisan migrate:rollback runs the down() function.

Answer (score 6):

For rollback of single table,

```
php artisan migrate:rollback  --path=/database/migrations/22_03_18_010_create_users_table.php
```

For rollback and re-migrate at the same time,

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/22_03_18_010_create_users_table.php
```

This command will save your time to drop and re-migrate a table after editing, often beginners drop the migration and then migrate it again after changes.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to Delete the table and run the Migration again. Just run the artisan command.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

> Note: It will drop all tables and re-run migration.

or if you have the seed of tables then run this command

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Reference: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)

Answer (score 3):

Create a migration in the console with the following;-

```
php artisan make:migration drop_table_name_table;
```

Then you need edit the up() function in that migration to be something like;-

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::drop('table_name');
}
```

Then run that migration to compelete the task.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've made some edits to your post to fix grammar. I realise english probably isn't your first language, however when posting try to avoid  casual abbreviations like using "u" for "you", and capitalise the start of sentences and put in punctuations like the full stop.  The substance of the post was correct, and I'll give you an upvote, but try and remember to make sure your grammar and english are at least somewhat formal. Stack Overflow can be an unforging place sometimes, so keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `php artisan db:wipe` that way you are going to force laravel to drop all tables regardless foreign keys constraints or like in your case if you forgot the `down()` method on your migration.

if you don't have a `down()` method on your migration, rollback is not going to work.

You can also use `php artisan migrate:fresh` this is going to force drop all tables and then is going to run all migrations

Answer (score 0):

Go to  migration table and in down function add this line:

```php
Schema::dropIfExists('tableName');
```

You will replace tableName with your table name in migration.

After adding it, open command line and remove this table with this command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1 --path=database/migrations/2022_12_12_050004_create_tableName.php
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the presences table from the DB in Laravel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDusF.png)

1. Create a migration called drop_presences_table
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps5Eq.png)
2. in the up() function of the migration file, write: Schema::dropIfExists('presences');
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7oJ2.png)
3. Run php artisan migrate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKJQA.png)