# How to delete table in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a probleme to delete a table in mysql with Laravel 5.

How delete table in laravel 5 ?

Not truncate table :

Comment: For as far as I know, that is exactly how you drop a table from within Laravel.

Answer (score 11):

You can run `php artisan migrate:rollback` command and if a table was created in a last batch, it will be deleted (if `down()` method of a migration was written correctly, of course).

If not, you can create a new migration and delete table with [`drop()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations) method:

```
Schema::drop('users');
```

Or:

```
Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Comment: i trie  Schema::drop('users'); but the table is not delete

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin In your migration file. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42344506/931247

Answer (score 2):

To delete records from the table:

`DB::table('table_name')->delete();`

If you wish to truncate the entire table, which will remove all rows and reset the auto-incrementing ID to zero, you may use the truncate method:

`DB::table('table_name')->truncate();`

Answer (score 2):

By fetching the DB instance via table name.

```
DB::table('table_name')->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Answer (score -4):

find the id of a row then perform an action

$obj=obj::find($id);

$obj->delete();