# How can drop colum in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is this query is correct?

I'm using Laravel 8, and I want to drop a column in a table. But this query isn't working.

```
php artisan make:migration remove_contact_no_from_customer --table=customer
```

Comment: That's not a query that create a migration. You can then run pending migrations using `php artisan migrate` assuming you've modified the generated migration file to make the changes you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42344506/15483718 see this link you will get your answer

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use To drop a column, you may use the [dropColumn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#dropping-columns) method on the schema builder blueprint:

first, you can create a migration file:

```
php artisan make:migration remove_contact_no_from_customer --table=customer
```

then, in that migration, make sure you code will be:

```
 Schema::table('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('contact_no');
        });
```

Comment: Sir, is this query is true? $ php artisan make:migration remove_contact_no_from_customer --table=customer

Comment: when removeable migration is created then, i do this  Schema::table('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('contact_no');
        });

Comment: no, this is not a query, it's a command to generate a migration file, in that migration file, you should usethe code i provided here

Answer (score 0):

```
To drop a table in laravel, Create a first migration

Step to drop a table

$ php artisan make:migration drop_user_table

Add this to your migrate file inside up function Schema::drop('tableName');

public function up() 
{
    Schema::dropIfExists(table('songs'));
    $table->increments('id');
    ...

}
then run

$ php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a query. It only creates a migration file in your `database/migrations` folder where you have to add some code like so:

```php
public function up() {
    Schema::table('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('contact_no');
    });
}
```

Afterward, just run `php artisan migrate` to apply your new migrations to the database, which will drop this column.